# Swift assignments inside conditions

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, swift2

I was wondering what this code does:

```
var something: String = "Hi"

if something = "Hello world!" {
    // Will this be executed?
}
```

Will it assign to `something` variable and do the `if` body? Or will it set the value of that variable only for the `if` body and outside it will not change? Or has it anything to do with `nil`?

Comment: TIAS: try it and see! Either type "swift" on the command line, or go to http://swiftstub.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern only works for assignments that can fail — that is, if you're assigning the result of an expression that returns an Optional value. And in that case, you use `if let`, not just `if`.

Answer (score 2):

Assignments are not expressions that return booleans, so cannot be used inside an `if` like this.  So this won’t compile.

(though you will get a misleading compiler message)

[image: assignment in if failing to compile]

Comment: With a completely unhelpful error message.  But does this still fail to compile if we have say `if something = funcThatReturnsOptionalString() {` ...?

Comment: @nhgrif your suggestion will fail too because you're missing `let` keyword. If you create a function which returns `String?` you'll have to unwrap this optional.

Answer (score 0):

we can't use assignment operator for if condition, you would you *if let* suppose if you are working with *optional types*

Here are some operators that helps you get clarity to differentiate from assignment operator

```
=   assignment operator
==  is equal to
=== is identical to
```